# how to rectify this problem so the app can run

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, tsx

error - Error [TypeError]: Failed to parse URL from undefined/api/common-settings                                           at new Request (evalmachine.:2352:19)                                                                        at Agent2.fetch (evalmachine.:3127:29)                                                                       at fetch (evalmachine.:6911:42)                                                                              at context.fetch (file://C:\Users\Bosta\Desktop\BOSTA-APTECH-LIB\Bit\alphaedge-labs\node_modules\next\dist\server\web\sandbox\context.js:198:24) {                                                                                            middleware: true                                                                                                      }

i tried using exceptions but the result was negative